# IP address is blacklisted after ajax post testing

Tags: php, ajax, cordova, ip-address, blacklist

I have been working on a cross-platform mobile application using Phonegap. I am storing/receiving user’s/other’s location every 10 (ten) seconds using jQuery, Ajax, POST, PHP, phpMySql. I have been testing this exhaustively on my computer, Android and iOS devices.

Suddenly it stopped working. When I checked the location/website where files/database are hosted, it’s showing ‘Access denied. Your IP address [XXX.XXX.XX.XX] is blacklisted. If you feel this is in error please contact your hosting providers abuse department.’. My website is hosted on JustHost. There is no IP address added in IP Deny Manager.

So, it was working on my phone (or other devices) on Mobile data but not on Wi-Fi.

After some times it started working normally. What could be reason for this? This gives me scary thoughts. What if app user’s IP address also get blacklisted? Why did it happen? Have I done some thing wrong? Or is it due to some other reasons?

Comment: If you feel this is in error please contact your hosting providers abuse department. Do that, they know their blacklists.

Comment: Most probably JustHost saw your repeated queries as some sort of attack. Contact them and ask for your IP address to be removed from the blacklist. Also you should change the way your app works. Contacting a remote server every 10 seconds is bad

Comment: @ChrisGhenea Could you please suggest some other way to achieve this? I need a map displaying my current location and other user's current location as a marker on the Google map. Also, other users should be able to see their , my and other's locations. As mentioned I am using AJAX(POST), PHP and phpMyAdmin for whole process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The server may think that this dDos attack.
In addition, a large number of post requests very heavy load server.
You can use websocket protocol and nodejs. This is the best solution. For example see the socket.io library (http://socket.io/).